# Maximization of Function with two restrictions.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Maximize

$$f(x,y,z)=xy+z^2,$$

while $2x-y=0$ and $x+z=0$. Lagrange doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Why doesn't Lagrange seem to work?

Comment: If $y=2x$ and $z=-x$ then $\left. f(x,\, y,\, z)\right|_{y=2x,\;z=-x}=f(x,\, 2x,\, -x)=\ldots$

Comment: Note that the set $A=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3; 2x-y=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad x+z=0\}$ is the image of the curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\gamma(t)=(t,2t,-t)$. Try maximize the function $f\circ \gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and you will obtain you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two constraints, we must use $$\nabla f(x,y,z)=\lambda\nabla g + \mu \nabla h.$$ 
We have

- $f(x,y,z)=xy+z^2$
- $g(x,y,z)=2x-y$
- $h(x,y,z)=x+z$

So we get
\begin{align}
f_x=\lambda g_x+\mu h_x &\implies y=2\lambda + \mu \tag{1} \\
f_y=\lambda g_y+\mu h_y &\implies x=-\lambda \tag{2} \\
f_z=\lambda g_z+\mu h_z &\implies 2z=\mu \tag{3}
\end{align}
with your constraint equations
\begin{align}
2x-y&=0 \tag{4} \\
x+z &=0 \tag{5}
\end{align}
Utilizing the system of equations $(1)$ to $(5)$, can you take it from here?